# Extract all delimited Word <b>...</b>

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a problem extracting words in MS Excel. I have multiple sentences in *HTML* format in a row and want to extract all of the words that are delimited by `<b>....</b>`

**Example:**

```
<b>buat</b> <i>v</i> <b>1</b> kerjakan; lakukan; <b>2</b> bikin;<br>--<b> cendol</b>
```

I want to extract the words: `"buat", "1", "2", "cendol"`

Can you help me to solve my problem? Any code in Excel/VBA is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something different, with splitting and joining and splitting again and looping trough array. I typed the text `<b>buat</b> <i>v</i> <b>1</b> kerjakan; lakukan; <b>2</b> bikin;<br>--<b> cendol</b>` in cell `A1`:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim MyWords As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim MyDelimiter As String
Dim MyLen As Byte

MyDelimiter = "||" 'Choose 1 not common delimiter
MyLen = Len(MyDelimiter)

MyWords = Split(Join(Split(Range("A1").Value, "<b>"), MyDelimiter), "</b>")

For i = 0 To UBound(MyWords) Step 1
    Debug.Print Mid(MyWords(i), InStr(1, MyWords(i), MyDelimiter) + MyLen, 99) 'Increase 99 if you are sure there will be longer texts between tags <b>..</b>
Next i

Erase MyWords
End Sub
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's a very easy way to do this by using an `HTMLDocument` object:

In your `VB Editor`, go to `Tools>References` and select the `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.

Then you can use the following code:

```
Sub extract()

Dim doc As New HTMLDocument 'Declare and create an object of type HTMLDocument
Dim item As HTMLObjectElement 'Declare an object of type HTMLObjectElement. We will use this to loop through a collection of HTML elements

doc.body.innerHTML = "<b>buat</b> <i>v</i> <b>1</b> kerjakan; lakukan; <b>2</b> bikin;<br>--<b> cendol</b> " 'Assign your HTML code as a string in doc body

For Each item In doc.getElementsByTagName("b") 'Loop through all the <b></b> elements in doc
    Debug.Print item.innerText 'print the text contained in <b></b> element. This will show up in your immediate window
Next item

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to be the most logic approach to use the possibilites of `HTMLDocument` when analyzing a `HTML` string +1 :-) FYI added a similar approach via XML just for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the worksheet function `FILTERXML` if you have Excel 2013+

First you need to change your string into a "well-formed" XML by enclosing it in an external tag, and closing off the unmatched `<br>` tag:

```
"<t>" & $A$1 & "</br></t>"
```

Then it's merely a matter of using an `Xpath` that will return all of the wanted tags:

```
FILTERXML("<t>" & $A$1 & "</br></t>","//b")
```

Wrapping that in an `INDEX` function allows you to extract the substrings one at a time:

**Full Formula** *entered in A3 and filled down*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t>" & $A$1 & "</br></t>","//b"),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: A very helpful addition :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Test()
Dim objReg      As Object
Dim objMatches  As Object
Dim match       As Object
Dim s           As String
Dim i           As Integer

s = "<b>buat</b> <i>v</i> <b>1</b> kerjakan; lakukan; <b>2</b> bikin;<br>--<b> cendol</b> "
Set objReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With objReg
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "<b>(.*?)<\/b>"
    Set objMatches = .Execute(s)
End With

For Each match In objMatches
    For i = 0 To match.Submatches.Count - 1
        Debug.Print Trim(match.Submatches.item(i))
    Next i
Next match

Set objReg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: A recommendable way though the search pattern doesn't comprise an empty tag structure like `<b/>` or `<b />` +1 :-)

Comment: I'd suggest, for `Pattern`:  `<b>([\s\S]+?(?=</b>))`  in case the substring extends over two lines or is empty.  Also note that, in vbscript, the `/` does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative using XML `DomDocument`**

Analyzing a `HTML` string it seems evident to use document object structures as in a `HTMLDocument` or in ►`XML`. That's why I demonstrate a further approach for the sake of completeness and in addition to *@StavrosJon 's* valid solution (which uses the more lenient `HTMLDocument` not needing to be well formed as XML is):

**Example call**

```
Sub ExtractViaXML()
  Dim html$, myArray()
  html = "<b>buat</b> <i>v</i> <b>1</b> kerjakan; lakukan; <b>2</b> bikin;<br>--<b> cendol</b> "
  myArray = getTokens(html, "b")                              ' assign findings to array via function getTokens()
  Debug.Print UBound(myArray) + 1 & " token(s) found: " & Join(myArray, ", ")  ' display results
End Sub
```

**Main function `getTokens()`**

```
Function getTokens(ByVal html$, Optional myTag$ = "b") As Variant()
' Purpose: isolate "<b>"-Tags (default value) out of html string and return found tokens as variant array
' Note:    creates temporary XML DOMDocument (late bound MSXML2 reference)
  Dim XmlString$
  XmlString = wellformed("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><tokens>" & html & "</tokens>")

  With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
      .ValidateOnParse = True: .Async = False
      If .LoadXML(XmlString) Then                              ' load xml string
          Dim myNodeList As Object
          Set myNodeList = .DocumentElement.SelectNodes(myTag) ' set node list to memory
          Dim i&, ii&, arr()
          ii = myNodeList.Length - 1                           ' calculate upper boundary of zero-based array
          If ii > -1 Then ReDim arr(ii)                        ' (re)dimension variant array arr()
          For i = 0 To ii                                      ' loop through node list
              arr(i) = myNodeList.item(i).Text                 ' assign each found text content to array
          Next i
          If ii = -1 Then arr = Array("**Nothing found**")     ' provide for zero findings
          getTokens = arr                                      ' return 0-based 1-dim array with found tokens
      Else: ShowParseError (.ParseError)                       ' optional: display possible error message
      End If
  End With
End Function
```

**Helper functions**

**XML** requires a *well formed* node structure with opening and closing tags or, whereas *HTML* is more lenient towards e.g. single line breaks(`<br>`). Therefore I added a simple function `wellformed()` to *cure* such an issue preventing successful loading. Furthermore I demonstrate using an optional procedure `ShowParseError` to localize (other) possible loading Errors which you can use as supplement to any `.load` or `.loadXML` function.

```
Function wellformed$(ByVal s$)
' Purpose: force a wellformed version of line breaks in html/xml string ("<br/>")
' Note:    unclosed tags like <br> only would prevent a successful load of the xml document
  wellformed = Replace(Replace(s, "</br>", "<br>"), "<br>", "<br/>")
End Function

Sub ShowParseError(pe As Object)
' Purpose: display possible parse error
' Note:    localizes error occurrence also by indicating position
        Dim ErrText$
        With pe
           ErrText = "Load error " & .ErrorCode & " xml file " & vbCrLf & _
           Replace(.URL, "file:///", "") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          .reason & _
          "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          "Line No.:    " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
          "Line Pos.: " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
          "File Pos.:  " & .filepos & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        End With
        MsgBox ErrText, vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to simulate this on excel. please check my sample solution below.

```
Sub test()

    Dim testString As String
    Dim startPos As Integer
    Dim endPos As Integer
    Dim resultString As String
    Dim str As String

    testString = "<b>buat</b> <i>v</i> <b>1</b> kerjakan; lakukan; <b>2</b> bikin;<br>--<b> cendol</b>"


    'get the position of start tag
    startPos = InStr(1, testString, "<b>") + 3

    'get the position of end tag
    endPos = InStr(startPos, testString, "</b>")


    Do While Len(testString) > 1

        'check if the start pos and end pos is correct
        If startPos > 0 And endPos > startPos Then

            'get the value in between the start tag and end tag
             str = Mid(testString, startPos, endPos - startPos)

             resultString = resultString + str + ","

             'remove the value retrieved from the original string
             testString = Mid(testString, endPos + 4)

             startPos = InStr(1, testString, "<b>") + 3
             endPos = InStr(startPos, testString, "</b>")

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

[image]